# Flutter font_awesome_flutter unavailable after installation

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to use the font_awesome_flutter package.

I have added it to dependencies

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  http: ^1.0.0
  internet_connection_checker: ^1.0.0+1

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  cached_network_image: ^3.3.1
  sqflite: ^2.0.0
  path: ^1.8.3
  flutter_widget_from_html: ^0.14.11
  url_launcher:
  font_awesome_flutter: ^10.7.0
```

I have retrieved the package. If I try again, I receive the message which suggests it is already installed

> "font_awesome_flutter" is already in "dependencies". Will try to
> update the constraint.

But I cannot include the file in my project

```
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
```

> Target of URI doesn't exist:
> 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart'.

Comment: Have you run `flutter pub get`? Does it complete with errors?

Comment: No errors. A few dependency messages.
flutter pub get
Resolving dependencies... 
  ffi 2.1.0 (2.1.2 available)
  http 1.2.0 (1.2.1 available)
  matcher 0.12.16 (0.12.16+1 available)
  material_color_utilities 0.5.0 (0.8.0 available)
  meta 1.10.0 (1.12.0 available)
  path 1.8.3 (1.9.0 available)
  test_api 0.6.1 (0.7.0 available)
  url_launcher_web 2.2.3 (2.3.0 available)
  video_player_web 2.1.3 (2.2.0 available)
  web 0.3.0 (0.5.0 available)
Got dependencies!
10 packages have newer versions incompatible with dependency constraints.

Comment: You just need to restart your IDE then.